# ¿Cómo separar una URL por partes en PHP usando la barra / o de otra forma?

Tags: php

En mi web estoy implementando una especie de URLs amigables que en realidad funcionan como si fuera una API.

Por ejemplo escribo esto:

```
www.example.com/lecturas/20181004
```

Yo recibo esa petición en un archivo PHP en el cual debo determinar:

- Si lo que hay en la parte de `lecturas` es correcto
- Si `20181004` es una fecha válida

Esas dos cosas no me dan problemas. La cuestión es que para hacer eso es evidente que debo obtener por separado lo que el usuario escribió en las dos últimas partes de la URL.

Lo estoy haciendo leyendo el valor `REQUEST_URI` de `$_SERVER` así:

```
$uriData=explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Eso me crea un array, **pero con una clave `0` que está vacía**:

```
var_dump($uriData);
```

Me arroja:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(8) "lecturas"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "20181004"
}
```

Está bien, yo puedo ignorar esa clave `0` y obtener mis partes así:

```
$endPoint  = $uriData[1];
$paramDate = $uriData[2];
```

Pero me pregunto si no hay una mejor forma de hacerlo.

Estaba revisando los datos que hay en `$_SERVER`, y no veo ninguno que me permita hacerlo de una mejor manera.

¿Cómo puedo crear un array limpio, únicamente con la información de la URL?

Comment: Hay alguna razón en particular por la que quieras obtener un array de solo 2 elementos ? Porque en ingeniería si funciona, dejalo como está

Comment: @blov80 la razón es que me crea un array donde el primer elemento está en blanco, no me parece correcto que haga eso. Imagino que habrá alguna forma de tener solamente los elementos que necesito y nada más.

Comment: Puedes quitar de forma sencila el primer slash con substr o con ltrim, por ejemplo $uriData=explode("/",substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 1));

Comment: @Carmen muchas gracias. En efecto era una de las ideas que tenía. Aunque a raíz de tu comentario me pregunto: ¿qué carga más el código, dejar que produzca el array como lo hace ahora, con el índice `0` en blanco, o aplicar una función adicional como `substr` para limpiar el dato?

Comment: Puesto que la conversión en array la vas a hacer en cualquier caso, lo lógico sería pensar que un substr o ltrim van a suponer mayor carga que mantener un elemento vacío en el array, tendría más sentido desde este punto de vista si fueras a eliminar una cantidad de información mayor que un slash o a utilizar el resultado intermedio en otra operación en tu página.

Comment: Entendido @Carmen. Propongo que aportes una respuesta indicando una o más formas de hacerlo y haciendo constar en una nota que lo más simple sería permitir que el array cree esa primera clave vacía. En cualquier caso, si hubiera que quitar el primer slash, lo más simple quizá sería: `$urlRequest = ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/');` Mi esperanza era poder encontrar otro forma de obtener solamente `lecturas/20181004` examinando la información de `$_SERVER`  u otra, pero parece que no es posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quitar de forma sencila el primer slash se puede hacer por ejemplo con `substr`

```
$uriData=explode("/",substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 1));
```

o `ltrim`:

```
$uriData=explode("/",ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/"));
```

Si bien cabe observar que como en cualquiera de estos casos se va a generar un array con `explode`, es probable que en el funcionamiento de la página suponga menos carga mantener un primer elemento vacío en el array que ejecutar una segunda función previa a este `explode`. Si se fuera a eliminar una gran cantidad de información, o bien el resultado intermedio se fuera a utilizar en otra operación en la misma página, si podría resultar una aproximación de utilidad.